# Files hidden on desktop on iMac M1

Tags: macos, finder

I recently bought a new iMac and I have the following problem: all the files present on the desktop disappeared. If I display hidden files, physically, they are still present but they are hidden. If I force  Finder to display hidden files or if I enter `ls -la` in the terminal, all the files are present.

I use iCloud Drive to synchronize my data with my different devices (iPhone, iPad Pro and MacBookPro) the files are available on all these devices, my only problem is with my iMac M1 computer.

Do you have any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution:
I ran the command `chflags -R nohidden .` in the Desktop folder twice and the files reappeared

Answer (score 1):

In System Settings select "Desktop & Dock" and then check if the "Show Items On Desktop" checkbox is checked.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't solve the problem. I have some items displayed on the Desktop and some others are not displayed. For me, it seems to be related to iCloud and M1. I tried to look at the permissions of the files and folders, some of them had extended attributes. I removed them with sudo xattr -cr * but the files and folder are still hidden.